# linked list ==> Which one is correct implementation of linked list

Tags: linked-list

I have two  set of codes :

```
class node :
 def __init__(self,data=None):
    self.data = data  # Assign data
    self.next = None  # Initialize
class linked_list :
 def __init__(self):
    self.head = node()
 def append(self,data):
    new_node = node(data)
    cur = self.head
    while cur.next!= None :
         cur = cur.next
    cur.next = new_node
 def display(self):
    elements = []
    cur_node = self.head
    while cur_node.next !=None:
        cur_node = cur_node.next
        elements.append(cur_node.data)
    print(elements)
```

upon  calling it

```
mylist = linked_list() #initialize linked list
mylist.append(3) #appending elements
mylist.append(4) #appending elements
mylist.append(5) #appending elements
mylist.append(6) #appending elements
mylist.display() #calling display
```

it Returns `[3,4,5,6]`

And

```
class linkedListNode :
 def __init__(self,data= None):
    self.data = data
    self.nextNode = None
class linkedList:
 def __init__(self):
    self.head = linkedListNode()
 def addNode(self,data):
    newNode = linkedListNode(data)
    if not self.head :
        self.head = newNode
    else :
        newNode.nextNode = self.head
        self.head = newNode
 def displayList(self):
    elements = []
    cursor = self.head
    while cursor.nextNode!=None:
        elements.append(cursor.data)
        cursor = cursor.nextNode
    return elements
```

Upon running returning :

```
mylist = linkedList()
mylist.addNode(3)  
mylist.addNode(4)   
mylist.addNode(5)  
mylist.addNode(6)  
myLinkedListElements = mylist.displayList() 
print(myLinkedListElements)
```

it Returns `[6,5,4,3]`

Which is right ?
This should be like this as per my understanding :

Head/first node -> 2nd node ->last node -> null

Pointers pointing towards one another. last node pointing to null.
So I think  6 should be the new head node

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. The documentation of the chosen implementation should clarify at which end of the list a new value is added.

Comment: You should tell _us_ which one is right... the "right" output is a business requirement, not an objective universal truth. Also, what language is this?

Comment: it is in python.